Causal Inference: Meta Learners usage
I have been running causal inference using Econ ML package on my data. I have a dataset containing customers divided into treatment and control and many other features. I run matching on those and obtained a matched dataset that contains the matched treat and control. If I calculate the difference in the avg outcome Y between the 2 matched group I get an ATE of 3.
Now my question is if I train a Meta Learner, ex. X learner on the data before match and then use it to estimate the ATE on that matched dataset I have, am I supposed to get an ATE very close to 3? Or not? If not what is the reason? This is the part that is not clear to me.

Disclaimer I just read the Econ ML package right now, very briefly. I also am not sure how "matching" comes into the model. Take my answer with a grain of salt, I may have misunderstood.
TL;DR Your first estimate (with the "matching") is closer to the reality because the "matching" is likely to correct for the unobserved heterogeneity.
My understanding is that Econ ML (links below, please check if I got the right package and models) is an extension of the traditional instrumental variables estimation. If so, then if the instruments are highly correlated with the controls, and the instrument itself does not suffer from an omitted variable bias, then the two ATE estimations should be closer to each other. Otherwise, they can be different. (Alternatively, if treatment and control are assigned randomly, then the two estimations will also be similar. However, from reading the model, this does not seem to be the case.)
While I am not sure about what "matching" means, it sounds like you are running two different procedures, where the first procedure corrects for the omitted variable bias through "matching". If this is the case, then consider the following for an intuition: Try to predict likelihood of death within the next year with only one variable, whether a person has visited a hospital. The coefficient will be positive, and you could make the argument that going to the hospital causes the likelihood of dying to increase, that the ATE is a positive number. Clearly this is incorrect, that's because you have not randomly assigned going to hospital, rather, people with underlying issues self-selected into going to the hospital. You do not observe this underlying condition, so the model suffers from omitted variable bias. Now consider that you want to correct for the fact that you failed to include the unobserved variable. You may want to use distance from the hospital as an instrument (bad idea in reality but good for an example). Or you wanted to "match" the people in a control group to similar people in the treatment group, perhaps using the distance from a hospital as your measure of similarity. Now you are beginning to control for the data you have been missing (omitted variable bias). So you may get closer to the actual ATE, assuming that you chose a "good" instrument.
In other words, your first estimate (with the "matching") is closer to the reality because the "matching" is likely to correct for the unobserved heterogeneity.
https://econml.azurewebsites.net/spec/motivation.html
https://econml.azurewebsites.net/spec/api.html

I thanks for your answer with Matching I mean propensity score matching. So we obtain 2 groups of treatment and control that are now matched on the variables we used in the propensity model
